# How to specify port range used by JDK's orbd.exe (Object Request Broker Daemon)?

Tags: java, corba, jacorb

We have a legacy application that is using CORBA for communiction between two Java processes on different machines. We are using the ORBD.exe from JDK as a Object Request Broker. In all existing environments there were no restrictions regarding the used ports between these two machines.
This application has now to be installed at another customer and they refused to open up all ports between the two workstations that are communicating via CORBA. Is there a way to configure ORBD.exe in a way that is uses only a range of let's say 20 ports?
I searched around a little bit and found out that JacORB for example provides parameters for that (jacorb.net.socket_factory.port.min / jacorb.net.socket_factory.port.max) but regarding https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/idl/orbd.html ORBD.exe seems only to allow the specification of the port where the name server is listening for new connections (-ORBInitialPort, default 1050) and another port which's usage I don't understand (-port, default 1049). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think orbd has a -port option. So you should just say `orbd -port 9999`. The default port is 1049.

Comment: Maybe my information is not correct, but isn't ORBD a server that can serve multiple clients and all of these clients is using a different port (dynamically allocated after the client registers at the ORBInitialPort 1050 at ORBD? So how could a single parameter help with this?

Comment: Ok, we did some more testing now. It is as I expected: When starting orbd.exe with -ORBInitialPort 1050 but without -port option it uses 1050 and 1049 as well as multiple other higher ports (52261, 52262 etc.). When starting orbd.exe with -ORBInitialPort 1050 -port 9999 it uses 1050 and 9999 as well as multiple other higher ports. What I want to specify is the range for these multiple other higher ports. Any ideas?